# Custom look and feel images for JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, joptionpane, synth

I'm creating a custom look and feel using XML based on the `SynthLookAndFeel` class, and I was wondering. What style tag would I use to set the images on a JOptionPane?

EDIT: This is just one in specific that I was looking for, but if there is some sort of list of all the tags, that would be awesome.

Comment: there is RootPane or ContentPane

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, I know that. But what would I use as a tag to change it?